# How to publish a Node.js Server online so that it is always accessible by an outside application

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, localhost

I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem but for whatever reason I cannot find a clear answer as to how I can carry out this task.

I have built a very simple server with node.js that accesses two numbers from a website API and outputs them onto a localhost port on my computer as shown below:

My question is how can I take my server and make it accessible to applications without having to go into the command line and run the server file?  Is there a way I can host it online instead of locally so that I can distribute the application and anyone with the application can pull from this server?  What would be the best way to go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: You either buy a static IP address for your home internet connection and then punch a hole in your home firewall (not recommended) and access it via an IP address or you find a hosting site that supports node.js apps and you pay them to host your server and probably buy a domain that you can hook up to your IP address. FYI, you will probably want to fix your `onRequest()` handler so it only runs on a certain URL such as `/getStatus` so you can add other URLs in the future and so if a browser hits your server, your request handler doesn't run when the browser is just trying to get the icon.

Comment: you can get a vm from digital ocean for 5 bucks a month, and for even less from less-reputable places, down to $20/year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku is probably one of the easiest ways to get started with deploying the application: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

However, if you are not familiar with `git`, Microsoft Azure Webapps is also another great option: https://tryappservice.azure.com/

They both offer free plans which should get you up and running fast!

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1: how can I take my server and make it accessible to applications without having to go into the command line and run the server file?**

To start a node server you will always need to use the console. If you are not used to,it's time to start :) .
You will be using it not only for node servers but for administrating (almost) every server in the world.

**Question 2: Is there a way I can host it online instead of locally ?**

There are a lot of nodejs hosting platforms, you can choose between [PaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) solutions or IaaS solutions ( [AWS EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/it/ec2/), [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/),  etc.) . Probability the easiest way to start ar PaaS services, in this [blogbost](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/a-comparison-of-node-js-paas-hosting-providers/) you will find a good list of PaaS hosting providers. Some of them have free plans.

Comment: IIS/win servers are not always administered from the command line, which is probably the only reason people still buy into them.

Comment: Yes, I know, but soon or later if you are running a production server on ISS/win you will need the console, maybe just for the ping command, but still you are going to use it :D

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/). They have a free tier (with limitations) and a hobby tier for $7/month.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented that with Amazon AWS, they offer free option for a limited time, but still great because you have full control on the console, you should be careful while installing the machine on cloud, you have many guides online that you can follow for steps, [this](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/05/setup-node-development-environment-amazon-ec2/) one for example has step by step info, try to follow the steps and you will be able to run your app and access it from any public network.